# How to get the tilt angle in a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, accelerometer

My application for Windows Phone 8 needs the angle by which the phone is tilted. I think accelerometer can be used to do it but I don't know how. Is there any way to calculate the tilt of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/09/08/using-the-accelerometer-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) blog has very nice explanation on how to use accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone/tutorials/level) a while ago, didnt think that it would be in use so soon :)